# How can I exclude columns with blank cell while using the filter function?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am currently using google spreadsheet to record each answer from google forms to google spreadsheets by categorizing it by name (ex. salesperson). I successfully categorized each name by using some codes and that results to automatic new sheet tab rename to the name of the person whenever new answer is entered in google sheet.

However, there are columns in my form responses that have blank cells, and I want to exclude it from copying whenever I categorized each answer.

In every tab, I use this formula to filter the name to another sheet

**=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:J, Sheet1!A2:A="John") (for example, the name is John, where I want him to have his own sheet on my google spreadsheet)**

However, the columns with blank cells also copies. What formula should I add to filter to exclude those columns with blank cells from copying?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can add more condition. Suppose you want to exclude column B having black cells. Then write formula like `=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:J, Sheet1!A2:A="John",Sheet1!B2:B<>"")`

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample data set of what you're dealing with. Is it any column? One specific column?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.